# Can I send the BGE image, with alpha layer to other SW like openCV or OBS studio?

Tags: game-engine, transparency

I would like to overlay 3D video with tranparency generated by the BGE over a real-time video.

So, I supposed that I have to access to the images buffer(with RGBA pixel) and send it to openCV or OBS. But is it possible?

Thank you in advance,
Arnaud

Comment: It's a good question but I think that they answer it in stack exchange, here they only limit themselves to python and they do not give for more